# How to disable other divs coming from loop except the clicked one

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, local-storage

I have some `li` tags whose data is coming from a loop. When I click any `li` tag it will become active by changing its image and will store into localstorage so that on refresh the clicked one is still active. Here when we click, an active object is adding to json the clicked `li` tag and stores it in localstorage. Now the problem is when I click again on the clicked `li`  tag or outside it, it's toggling the earlier image, which should not be happening. Again, other `li` tags should be disabled except the clicked one. Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skzgno?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div>
    <pre>

  </pre>
    <ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of statusdata" (click)="toggleActive(item, !item.active)">
  <span>{{item.id}}</span>
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <span>
    <img *ngIf="!item?.active || item?.active === false" src ="https://dummyimage.com/qvga" />
    <img *ngIf="item?.active === true" src ="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff" />
  </span>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  statusdata: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.statusdata = [
      { id: 1, name: "Angular 2" },
      { id: 2, name: "Angular 4" },
      { id: 3, name: "Angular 5" },
      { id: 4, name: "Angular 6" },
      { id: 5, name: "Angular 7" }
    ];

    this.statusdata.forEach(item => {
      this.getCacheItemStatus(item);
    });
  }

  toggleActive(item, activeStatus = true) {
    item.active = activeStatus;
    localStorage.setItem(`item:${item.id}`, JSON.stringify(item));
  }

  getCacheItemStatus(item) {
    const cachedItem = localStorage.getItem(`item:${item.id}`);
    if (cachedItem) {
      const parse = JSON.parse(cachedItem); // Parse cached version
      item.active = parse.active; // If the cached storage item is active
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me on it

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you just need to add some logic to your `toggleActive` method. You could check if any items are active before deciding whether or not to do anything about the click. Does something like this solve your problem?

```
toggleActive(item, activeStatus = true) {
   if(item.active || !this.statusdata.some(d => d.active)){
      item.active = activeStatus;
      localStorage.setItem(`item:${item.id}`, JSON.stringify(item));
   } 
}
```

Comment: It's working now I removed first conditions from if,but how to disabled other li after click which are not active

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a bit unsure what you're asking. When do you want the click to have an  effect? You just need to update the `if` condition to match your requirement.

Comment: Once you click any li you cannot click other li again. Those Will be disabled

Comment: What should happen if the user clicks on the same `li` again? Should the other ones become enabled again?

Comment: No, nothing will happen

Comment: Sounds to me like removing the first condition from the `if` should be fine then. What do you mean by "how to disabled other li after click which are not active"? Are you  still stuck with something?

Comment: Please open it in full browser https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skzgno?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  , Then click button/image of any li tag,The button will changed to different image as like active .Even if you refresh also this active will not be change since we are adding active=true into localstorage.Now the problem is,when you click button of any li,except that button,buttons of other li should be disable.

Comment: You've disabled all the buttons to start with, because they don't start as active. Your disabled binding needs to consider whether or not any items are active. I think we've wandered beyond the scope of this question, but think about the logic for when items should be disabled. If you get stuck, you can always ask another question, and list the approaches that you've tried (and what was wrong with each one).